# Finding same-vectors that have same coordinates in two different basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have two different vector basis:

- Default: $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\} = \{(1,0,0);(0,1,0);(0,0,1)\}$
- *Special* basis: $\{e'_1,e'_2,e'_3\} = \{(1,1,1);(1,0,1);(0,2,1)\}$

**My question is:** How do I find which vectors (if there are any) whom have the same coordinates whether they are written in default or *special* basis vector space coordinates.

*Example:* The **null vector** has the coordinates $(0,0,0)$ in both default and *special* basis.

---

Through Gaussian elimination I established that the coordinates $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ in regular basis, becomes $$([x'_1+x'_2];\,[x'_1+2x'_3];\,[x'_1+x'_2+x'_3])$$ after transformation to *special* basis.

Likewise, the coordinates $(x'_1,x'_2,x'_3)$ in *special* basis, becomes $$([2x_1+x_2-2x_3];\,[-x_1-x_2+2x_3];\,[-x_1+x_3])$$
after transformation to default basis.

As such, I tried setting:

$$\begin{cases}
x_1 = 2x_1+x_2-2x_3 \\
x_2=-x_1-x_2+2x_3 \\
x_3 = -x_1+x_3
\end{cases}$$

Which has the trivial answer $x_1=x_2=x_3=0$.

Can I now conclude there are no (except the null vector) same-vectors which have same coordinates in both basis?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what eigenvalues are yet. :Z

Comment: for your basis change write a matrix and check their eigenvalues. For example http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigensystem+%7B%7B1%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C2%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C1%7D%7D

Comment: @janmarqz Watched a video from Khan Academy on Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors. From what I understood, $\lambda$ needs to equal 1 in order for a vector to have the same coordinates in both basis. Does this mean there are no such vectors in my case? (Going by your Wolfram link)

Comment: Updates my question to include an attempt which I'm unsure if it is enough to draw a conclusion from.

Comment: since there is no eigenvalue = 1, then there is no vector with the same components in both bases, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution looks perfectly valid. A very direct approach would be to say that you're looking for triples satisfying:
$$xe_1+ye_2+ze_3=xe'_1+ye'_2+ze'_3$$
which doesn't require every doing any change of basis. Taking each coordinate alone, it yields the equations
$$x=x+y$$
$$y=x+2z$$
$$z=x+y+z$$
which, when solved, yields $x=y=z=0$ as the only solution.

A slightly more sophisticated solution could take the above equations and rearrnage each to read, by subtracting lefthand side from righthand side:
$$0=y$$
$$0=x-y+2z$$
$$0=x+y$$
where each equation defines a plane (or more conveniently, a linear subspace of dimension $2$) in $\mathbb R^3$ - the normal vectors to these planes being $(0,1,0),\,(1,-1,2),\,(1,1,0)$. The set of solutions to this will form a linear subspace, and thus be either a plane, a line, or a point (the origin). Since, clearly, $(0,1,0)$ and $(1,-1,2)$ are not parallel, the intersection of the planes normal to them is a line parallel to their cross product, $(2,0,-1)$. However, this line is not on the plane normal to $(1,1,0)$ (since their dot-product is not zero), thus its intersection with that plane is just a point - which must be the origin. More generally, if the product
$$((e_1-e'_1)\times (e_2-e'_2))\cdot (e_3-e'_3)\neq 0$$
then the origin is the only vector satisfying this.